# rails active record association, fill up foreign key using build from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations

I'm building a very simple rails association and testing it through console. I have a User model and a Courses model. These are associated in the following way:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :courses, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :teacher, :foreign_key => 'teacher_id', :class_name => 'User'
end
```

When testing through console I need to have a user_id column in the courses table in order to run

```
User.first.courses.build
```

However, doing that I am left with an empty teacher_id in the courses table.

I would like to know if it is possible to have only a teacher_id column in the courses table (no user_id which seems to me redundant) and to fill it up automatically running

```
User.first.courses.build
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error in my associations.

The user model should be associated to the course through teacher_id:

```
 has_many :taught_courses, :foreign_key => :teacher_id, :class_name => "Course", :dependent => :destroy
```

In this way everything works as expected